# Tate cohomology of units

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, class-field-theory, local-field

Show that for any local field K, there is a finite Galois extension L, such that $H^{i}_{T}(Gal(L/K),O_L^*)$ does not vanish for all i, here $O_L$ is ring of algebraic integers of L.

I only know that for unramified extension L/K, such cohomology always vanish. I do not know how to construct one with converse property.

Comment: For every  totally ramified cyclic extension $K\subset L$, all Tate cohomology groups of $O_L^*$ are cyclic of order $[L:K]$.